# How to write a compact list terms through set notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I would like to ask a question about a mathematical notation used in economics, because I'm not an expert on it. I'm studying an economic model in which I understood measure theory is used, but I'm not sure because it has not been told. There are definitions in which there are summations for every element of a particular set.

For example, the definition of the composite good, one of the goods which are consumed in the model, which has n regions, is the following, in the slides

$$M_{r}=\Big [\sum_{s\in R} \int_{i \in N_s} [q_{sr}(j)]^{(\sigma -1)/\sigma} dj\Big ]^{\sigma/(\sigma-1)}$$

r, is the region in which the good is consumed, s is the region in which the good is produced, j is the variety of the good, R is the set of regions, $N_s$ is the mass of firms - I know there is a continuum of firms - and I have a question: if I want to write all the composite goods consumed in all regions, can I write under the M  $r \in R $ and under the summation sign $s,r \in R$? I mean, am I writing all the composite goods with this notation, or am I doing an exception with mathematics just to get to the point?

I'd like just to write all the R composite goods in the correct way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd write $$\sum\limits_{r \in R}M_r =\sum\limits_{r \in R}\left[\sum_{s \in R}\int\limits_{i \in N_s}[q_{sr}(j)]^{(\sigma - 1)/\sigma}dj\right]^{\sigma/(\sigma - 1)}$$
but I don't know if there's some other standard notation used in the field - it may well be that there's some other name given to this thing (and if I was writing it a lot, I'd probably come up with a name for it just to avoid having to deal with $\sum_{r\in R}M_r$ every time).

However, there are a couple of things which I can say for certain:

1. $M_{r\in R}$ doesn't work unless you define it first: what does that mean? How are we combining all of these things? I don't know, unless you tell me (unless this is standard in the field, in which case just follow the standard).
2. Combining the two sums definitely doesn't work, even if you define it: this is a problem of mathematics, rather than notation: if we throw out the extraneous part by  assuming $\sigma/(\sigma - 1) = 2$ and that $R$ only has two elements (neither of these actually matter - the problem appears regardless, except in a handful of essentially silly cases), then what you're after is something of the form

$$(a + b)^2 + (c + d)^2$$ (where $a$ and $b$ are the values of the two integrals with $r$ equal to our first value, and $c$ and $d$ the other two).

However, if you write the sums combined, what you've written down is instead $$(a + b + c + d)^2,$$ which is not the same thing at all (for example, if $a = b = c = 1$, then the first gives us $2^2 + 2^2 = 8$, whereas the second gives us $4^2 = 16$).

Comment: Ok, M is the composite good which is a sum of quantity of varieties j consumed all together. This varieties are produced in the s region and consumed in all the regions (s included), so when we talk about $M_r$ we are mentioning the composite good consumed in region r, derived from productions in all regions. There will be R composite goods. I'd like to know if I can write the entire list as I said before: $M_r \hspace{5mm} \forall r \in R \hspace{5mm} ... \hspace{5mm} \sum_{s,r \in R} \hspace{5mm} ...$

Comment: As I said: no, you can't, because $(a + b)^c \neq a^c + b^c$ in general.

Comment: ok, thanks. I think I made was wrong because I mistook the concept of belonging for the concept of index of a summation. If I write $$M_{r}= \sum_{s \in R} \hspace{5mm} ... \forall s,r \in R$$ ? The double summation is not adeguate because I know I have a list, not a total sum, it's why I'm asking.

Comment: The problem is that it *isn't* $M_r = \sum \cdots$. It's $M_r = (\sum \cdots)^{\sigma/(\sigma-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the point, how can I write an entire list of results that belongs to a set? M is an element of a set, and it is derived trough s and r that belong to R

Comment: You write it exactly how I wrote it above, with two separate sums. Combining them is simply nonsense, because we're doing non-linear things to the inner sum.